# How to validate Username and password with Webserver values in I phone application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am developing view based application.I have login page when we click on Login button it should check entered values with webserver values and it should display vali or invalid.I have wriiten code in this way it is executing successfully i am getting the result in this way

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUbLIC" -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict....
```

What i need to change in below code to comapre with server values..can any one help me regarding this please...

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{

    NSString* username = nameInput.text;
    NSString* pass = passInput.text;

    if([nameInput.text isEqualToString:@"" ]|| [passInput.text isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {

        greeting.text = @"Input Your Value";
        [nameInput resignFirstResponder];
        [passInput resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    NSString *post = 
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"uname=%@&pwd=%@",username,pass];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://108.16.210.28/Account/LogOn"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];  
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {

    }

    [nameInput resignFirstResponder];
    [passInput resignFirstResponder];
    nameInput.text = nil;
    passInput.text = nil;

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{


    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(loginStatus);
    greeting.text = loginStatus;
    [loginStatus release];



    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: We're not here to debug your code. What, specifically, isn't working? What have you tried?

Comment: Code is working fine but based on code i should be able to connect web server and if server values match with entered values it should display messages valid invalid but i am getting application first line of html code

Answer (score 0):

Use `statusCode` to see the login state.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

   if([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
   {
       NSHTTPURLResponse *theResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
       NSInteger theStatusCode = [theResponse statusCode];
       }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.after adding the status code also i am getting same previous output

Comment: what value are you seeing in the Status Code?

Comment: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"uname=%@&pwd=%@",username,pass];

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the data.If it is in the form of XML data then you have to parse the element (like valid) in the didfoundcharacters.If it is valid then make a variable like BOOL confirm = NO;Modify this in the didfoundcharacters.if (confirm) then give access further

Comment: How can i use .. can u give small example with description